# Cloudbees Jenkins doDelete for non-administrators

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees, jenkins-workflow

Is "run/delete" permission (as it is called on the error screen when trying to POST to doDelete) possible to give to non-administrators? If not, how can non-administrators kill hung workflow jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this permission can be granted to anyone.

Anyway what you really want is to upgrade Workflow to 1.11 with JENKINS-25550.